# How to get FAQ of your article on Google Search

Tags: plugins

I can see some websites FAQ appearing on Google Search when we search for a string.

The below image shows the FAQ on Google Search.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvA2n.png

Is there any plugin that is available for the same?

I tried many plugins but none of them worked.

Developer guide for FAQ to appear in search is listed here:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/faqpage

Thanks.

Comment: That is a SEO Question, not a wordpress question.

Comment: It's related to Wordpress plugin.

Comment: Which plugin are you talking about? I don't see a plugin name. It is a SEO question.

Comment: Dear Sir, did you understand the question? I am asking if there is any plugin with that feature. There are many but the ones I tested don't work. If you don't know kindly let others, who know, answer. Thank you.